# Firebase functions rewrites Angular dist/index.html and create errors + <app-root> appears blank

Tags: node.js, angular, express, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I have an Angular app that works when I run it in localhost.
When I run:

> firebase serve --only functions,hosting

it rewrites dist/index.html and add to it the following scripts:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="runtime.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="styles.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
```

Then I get this error (X12 times):

> http://localhost:5001/runtime.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

if I remove the scripts manually than the errors are gone but I see a blank page.

if I add

```
<h1>something</h1>
```

it renders it.

So what I understand is that from some reason I can't get  even though it when I inspect the page BUT it doesn't load the components so the page appears blank.

this is firebase.json:

```
 {
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html",
        "function": "app"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

even if I remove the "rewrites" section and rebuild the app, the scripts appear there.

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" class="full-height">
  <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Ezxpress</title>
      <base href="/">

      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  </head>
  <body>
    <app-root></app-root>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=apiKey"> async; defer</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

functions/index.js:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/myProject')));

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './../dist/myProject/index.html'));
});
exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app)
```

So I would like to get rid of those scripts and get the app-root.
Whats the problem with the rewrite? and how is it supposed to be codded?
thanks!